# Multiple group operations using Mongo aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb

Given a set of questions that have linked survey and category id:

```
> db.questions.find().toArray();
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fda05bc322b1c95b531ac25"),
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Question 1",
        "category_id" : 1,
        "survey_id" : 1,
        "score" : 5
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fda05cb322b1c95b531ac26"),
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Question 2",
        "category_id" : 1,
        "survey_id" : 1,
        "score" : 3
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fda05d9322b1c95b531ac27"),
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Question 3",
        "category_id" : 2,
        "survey_id" : 1,
        "score" : 4
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fda4287322b1c95b531ac28"),
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "Question 4",
        "category_id" : 2,
        "survey_id" : 1,
        "score" : 7
    }
]
```

I can find the category average with:

```
db.questions.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$category_id",
        avg_score : { $avg : "$score" }
    }
}
);

{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "avg_score" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "avg_score" : 5.5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**How can I get the average of category averages (note this is different than simply averaging all questions)?**  I would assume I would do multiple group operations but this fails:

```
> db.questions.aggregate(
...   { $group : {
...     _id : "$category_id",
...     avg_score : { $avg : "$score" },
...   }},
...   { $group : {
...     _id : "$survey_id",
...     avg_score : { $avg : "$score" },
...   }}
... );
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: the _id field for a group must not be undefined",
    "code" : 15956,
    "ok" : 0
}
>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's important to understand that the operations in the argument to aggregate() form a *pipeline*.  This meant that the input to any element of the pipeline is the stream of documents produced by the previous element in the pipeline.

In your example, your first query creates a pipeline of documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "avg_score" : 5.5
},
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "avg_score" : 4
}
```

This means that the second element of the pipline is seeing a series of documents where the only keys are "_id" and "avg_score".  The keys "category_id" and "score" ***no longer exist*** in this document stream.

If you want to further aggregate on this stream, you'll have to aggregate using the keys that are seen at this stage in the pipeline. Since you want to average the averages, you need to put in a single constant value for the _id field, so that all of the input documents get grouped into a single result.

The following code produces the correct result:

```
db.questions.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$category_id",
        avg_score : { $avg : "$score" },
        }
    },
    { $group : {
        _id : "all",
        avg_score : { $avg : "$avg_score" },
        }
    }
);
```

When run, it produces the following output:

```
 {
    "result" : [
        {
        "_id" : "all",
        "avg_score" : 4.75
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm, didnt know you could use a constant.  I assume this approach wouldn't work for grouping at an even higher level.  Thanks, looks like it will work for this use-case though

Comment: If you want to group at a higher level you just need to make sure that the relevant keys are projected into the document stream by the first element of the pipe.  If you have a concrete example, feel free to post another question.