# MongoDb get last and max values with timestamps

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDb as I only installed it yesterday...

I have a collection of temperature readings from n rooms:

```
[
  {
    "key": "livingRoom",
    "name": "Living Room",
    "temp": 19.437,
    "ts": "2017-04-29T07:20:22.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key": "bedroom",
    "name": "Bedroom",
    "temp": 24.875,
    "ts": "2017-04-29T07:21:14.000Z"
  }
]
```

and I want to get the current (last) temperature and the min/max over the last 24 hours for each room. I also want the timestamp of the min and max values.
I am 90% of the way there but as always that last 10% seems to take 90% of the time.
I have this aggregation:

```
{   
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "temp": {"$last": "$temp"},
        "name": {"$last": "$name"},
        "ts": {"$last": "$ts"},
        "maxTemp": {"$max": "$temp"},
        "minTemp": {"$min": "$temp"}
    }
}
```

That produces this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "bedroom",
    "temp": 22.25,
    "name": "Bedroom",
    "ts": "2017-04-30T07:31:30.000Z",
    "maxTemp": 24.875,
    "minTemp": 21.437
  },
  {
    "_id": "livingRoom",
    "temp": 18.75,
    "name": "Living Room",
    "ts": "2017-04-30T07:39:38.000Z",
    "maxTemp": 19.625,
    "minTemp": 17.625
  }
]
```

but of course that doesn't include the timestamp of the min and max values.

This question:
[Multiple group operations using Mongo aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040662/multiple-group-operations-using-mongo-aggregation-framework) was useful and seems to indicate that I can't do what I want to.
I was planning on using different groups with different sorts to get the different aggregations that I want but as a group acts on the result of the last group it seems that what I am trying to do can't be done by mongo.

Comment: Have you tried placing a $sort pipeline step before the $group?

Comment: I can either use the existing sort to get the last reading or I can sort to get the min/max temperatures. I can't sort to get both.