# How can i use multiple group stages in mongodb aggregate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, aggregate

Mongo query fails to return any input in case, I increase the number of `group stages` in my query. Below is the snippet of the query which I am using,

```
.group({
    _id: "$date",
    count: {
        $sum: 1
    },

})
/*
.group({
    _id: "$joinDate",
    count: {
        $sum: 1
    },

})
.group({
    _id: "$applyDate",
    count: {
        $sum: 1
    },

})*/
```

Comment: Without knowing your data structure, it's difficult to troubleshoot. However, this is a nice [explanation of how $group works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055679/8943092). It may address your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by the following way

```
yourModel.aggregate([ { $group : { _id : "$date" } } ] )
```

This might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@CsAlkemy, It is because the fields you are trying to use are not propagated after the `$group` stage.

For example, consider the following sample document and an aggregate query on the document,

```
{
    "name": "SV",
    "age": 21,
    "school": "KV",
    "city": "Ajmer"
}
```

Aggregate Query

```
db.temp.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$school",
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : "KV", "count" : 1 }
```

As you can see the fields which we get are only `_id` and `count` and the other fields `name, age, school and city` are lost and can't be used later.

Comment: @CsAlkemy, If you need additional help, you can updated your question with the requirements of your query, and I can help you from there.